# I dont know why my project in django return ModuleNotFoundError: No module named -

Tags: python, django, python-decouple

I have a django project with gunicorn and nginx.
Everything was going well, but when I installed decouple for the environment variables, it started to give me the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '-'
```

What can I do to fix it? Let me know if you need more files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: I deleted the project and re-uploaded it from GitHub and everything works again. It looked like some package got corrupted.